# CSS: After deleting a style, it still shows up

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, browser-cache

After deleting some of my CSS code in a rails application, I restart the server and refresh the page and I find the code is still being used. I can still see it when I use the Chrome element inspector.

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 961px) {
.logow {  position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;

}

body {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
background-image: url('bg.png');

}
}
```

For example, if I delete the `background-image: url('bg.png');` from my code, the background still stays the same. I am a CSS and rails noob so it is probably something very simple.

Comment: ctrl+F5, clear the cache in the browser :)

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks, did you mean `Shift`+`F5`?

Comment: press ctl+shft+del and you can remove cache , cookiges wtever you want then load your page :-)

Comment: @AymanSafadi: No, I meant CTRL+F5

Comment: Hi guys, tried all of your suggestions, and nothings changed :(. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and you can remove cache, cookies and whatever you want, then load your page.

Comment: Didn't make any difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: then may bhe your css coming from some other file as well ..why dont you see the path from firebug from where its coming

Comment: Ok, that helped me find the problem. For some reason another css file was being loaded, even though in the html of that web page I was having problems, I included `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "index"%>`. It was picking up the properties for another page? I can only assume I don't fully understand the way css is loaded in rails. Thanks again

Comment: Naybe at some point you did `rake assets:precompile` and even though you are changing your .css / .scss files, the precompiled assets (located in `public/assets`) still take precedence, and they do contain the old styles. The way you can get rid of that is simply to delete the `public/assets` directory and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your browser is caching the page.

Make sure that you reload the page. Sometimes Opera still uses the old and cached style, which means that you should avoid Opera and use Chrome, Mozilla or Safari.

If you still have to work on Opera, <kbd>delete history</kbd>. Reload <kbd>F5</kbd> will be sufficient on Chrome, Mozilla or Safari

Comment: I have been using chrome. Never used Oprea. Thanks anyway